# How to remove a power from one side of an equation and put it on the other

Tags: exponentiation, curves

This is probably a dumb question, but I can't seem to figure this out.

The equation is $y^2 + 2x = 13$

Now I need in a curve equation form. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it not just $y=(\pm)\sqrt{13-2x}$?

Comment: Simple algebraic manipulation.

Comment: $y^2 + 2x = 13$ so $y^2 = 13 - 2x$ so $y = \pm \sqrt{13 -x}$.  It's worth noting the curve is not a function (but the was no reason to think it would be) nor can $x$ be any value greater than 6 and a half.